# get duplicate records in mysql on the basis of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table with columns names

```
ID,EMP_NAME,DEPARTMENT,VOTER ID, MOBILE NO,Driver_License_NO,REGISTRATION_DATE
```

No employee can be register with more than one department. If any employee got registered with more than department, it would be consider as DUPLICATE record. Duplicate record can judge on the basis of duplicate mobile no. or voter id no.

I want an output like this

```
Name | Previous Department | Current Department | Possible Reason for Duplication(Mobile or Voter ID)
```

Sorry for poor English

thanks

Comment: what uniquely identifies a employee? id? license_no?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to have the database do the checking.  So, after you clean your data, you should add a unique index.  Something like this (I'm not sure what defines an employee):

```
create unique index unq_atable_empname_department on atable(empname, department);
```

You can get all the duplicates using aggregation:

```
select empname, group_concat(distinct department) as departments
from atable
group by empname
having count(distinct department) > 1;
```

As for possible reasons, you should probably ask another question.  Provide sample data and explain what you mean by the possible reasons.  This answer is for the gist of the question, identifying duplicates.